# Too many process with /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start , is this normal?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04

When I run htop command, I see lot of process running

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

The site become very slow. Is this normal? Is any process trying to start it again and again?

Here is the screenshot (Can't add image due to reputation)

https://ibb.co/hK9XQk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default configuration on Ubuntu runs in a multiprocessing mode named "prefork" where Apache forks a number of child processes to handle incoming requests.  This is perfectly normal.

If your system becomes too slow, this might mean that you need to tune the configuration (e.g. the number of child processes Apache uses, but there is a lot more to it that just this factor). It also could mean a lot of other things. Impossible to tell.